# Best way of running select query twice or combining two queries | Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table `Orders`, which contains a `customer_id` and a `supplier_id`, `order_status` etc..:

```
order_id|customer_id|supplier_id
--------|-----------|-----------
1       |1          |2
```

Both `customer_id` and `supplier_id` are related to a `Users` table where their data is stored, such as `first_name` `last name`, `email` etc..:

```
user_id|first_name|last_name
-------|----------|---------
1      | Jon      | Doe
2      | Jane     | Doe
```

I need to run a query that will pull the order data and also pull the data for the Customer and Supplier from the Users table. E.g. the result needs to be:

```
order_id|customer_first_name|customer_last_name|supplier_first_name|supplier_last_name
--------|-------------------|------------------|-------------------|------------------
1       |Jon                |Doe               |Jane               |Doe
```

I have been trying a few different methods for this including Laravel method addSelect (which I could not get to work - got really weird 'method not found' error) and PHP array_merge (and others), but nothing seems to provide the required result.

Can anyone advise whether there is a particular best practice or way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: A [MySQL Join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would require `JOIN`-ing the `users` table to the `orders` table twice - first for `supplier_id` and then for `customer_id`. So, the query would be:

```
SELECT order_id, customer_id, u1.first_name as customer_first_name,
u1.last_name as customer_last_name,

supplier_id, u2.first_name as supplier_first_name, 
u2.last_name as supplier_last_name

FROM orders o
    INNER JOIN users u1 ON
        o.customer_id = u1.user_id
    INNER JOIN users u2 ON
        o.supplier_id = u2.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [PDO Transactions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php). Combined with a foreach loop I think something like this may work to your requirements.

```
  <?php 
$database->beginTransaction();
    $database->query("SELECT * FROM Orders ");
    $OrderData = $database->single();
    $database->query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user_id = :user_id");
    $database->bind(':user_id', $Data['customer_id']);
    $UserData = $database->single();
    foreach($UserData as $k=>$v)
    {
        $OrderData[$v] = $v;
    }
$database->endTransaction();
?>
```

The beauty about PDO transactions is if any query fails, nothing is returned and the whole thing is cancelled its an all or nothing affair.